# Trying to access a reference to a subclass of an abstract class

Tags: mongoengine

The relevant classes in my setup:

```
class Menu(DynamicDocument):
    date = DateTimeField(required=True, unique=True)
    ...
    items = ListField(ReferenceField('MenuItem', required=True, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Menu %r>' % self.date

class MenuItem(DynamicDocument):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }

    @staticmethod
    def get_class_type(payload):
        if payload == 'url':
            return MenuItemURL
        elif payload == 'string':
            return MenuItemOrdinary
        raise ValueError('Unknown payload type for menu item')

class MenuItemOrdinary(MenuItem):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    special = ListField(StringField(min_length=1, max_length=30), required=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MenuItemOrdinary %r>' % self.name

class MenuItemURL(MenuItem):
    url = URLField(required=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MenuItemURL %r>' % self.url
```

I'm trying to access the `items` field in the document with the code:

```
    menu = Menu.objects.get(date=viewdate)

    print menu
    print menu.items
```

which yields an error:

```
Menu object
...
File "/home/user/ll/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/dereference.py", line 148, in _fetch_objects
  object_map[(collection, doc.id)] = doc
AttributeError: 'MenuItem' object has no attribute 'id'
```

When I look at the db entry, I can see that the `items` field indeed has an array of references to documents that exist in the database:

[image: items]

Any ideas what's the culprit? I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that `MenuItem` is an abstract class, perhaps related to this [issue](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/837).

I'm running

```
flask-mongoengine==0.9.3
flask-restplus==0.10.1
mongoengine==0.13.0
pymongo==3.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are meaning, but I run the snippet bellow, it worked well~~ You'd better supply you sample code for us to run to reproduce the bug.

```
from mongoengine import *
from datetime import datetime

class MenuItem(DynamicDocument):
    meta = {
        'abstract': True
    }

    @staticmethod
    def get_class_type(payload):
        if payload == 'url':
            return MenuItemURL
        elif payload == 'string':
            return MenuItemOrdinary
        raise ValueError('Unknown payload type for menu item')


class Menu(DynamicDocument):
    date = DateTimeField(required=True, unique=True)
    items = ListField(ReferenceField('MenuItem', required=True, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Menu %r>' % self.date


class MenuItemOrdinary(MenuItem):
    name = StringField(required=True)
    special = ListField(StringField(min_length=1, max_length=30), required=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MenuItemOrdinary %r>' % self.name


class MenuItemURL(MenuItem):
    url = URLField(required=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MenuItemURL %r>' % self.url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/demo'
    connect(host=host)
    now = datetime.now()
    m = Menu(date=now)
    m.save()
    menu = Menu.objects.get(date=now)

    print menu
    print menu.items
```